# jQuery form .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two forms in my HTML

```
<form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia">
    <ul class="form">
        <li> <label>Centimetros:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="cmAtl2" id="cmAtl2"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo">
    <ul class="form">
        <li> <label>Minutos:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="minutosNat" id="minutosNat"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
        <li> <label>Segundos:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="segundosNat" id="segundosNat"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And this if statement (condition is working as intended, already tested) in an external file.

```
if(distancia) {
    $("#formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo").hide();
    $("#formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia").show();
} else {
    $("#formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia").hide();
    $("#formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo").show();
}
```

If the condition *distancia* is **not** met the code works as intended.

If the condition is met both forms are displayed.

Resulting in *formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia* always being displayed, and *formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo* being displayed only when it should be.

I tried changing the order of the forms, like so

```
<form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo">
    <ul class="form">
        <li> <label>Minutos:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="minutosNat" id="minutosNat"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
        <li> <label>Segundos:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="segundosNat" id="segundosNat"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia">
    <ul class="form">
        <li> <label>Centimetros:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="cmAtl2" id="cmAtl2"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And to my surprise now *formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo* is always displayed and *formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia* is only displayed when it should be.

Edit:
Whole div in case it matters

```
<div id="subpagina5" class="contenedor">
    <h1 class="encabezado">Registro de marca de un atleta en una disciplina</h1>
        <form id="formRegistroMarcaAtleta">
            <ul class="form">
                <li> <label>Disciplina:</label>
                    <select id="listaDisciplinasRegistroMarcaAtleta" class="listaDatos"></select>
                </li>
                <li> <label>Atleta:</label>
                    <select id="listaAtletasRegistroMarcaAtleta" class="listaDatos"></select>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo">
                <ul class="form">
                    <li> <label>Minutos:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="minutosRMA" id="minutosRMA"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
                    <li> <label>Segundos:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="segundosRMA" id="segundosRMA"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
                </ul>
            </form>

            <form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia">
                <ul class="form">
                    <li> <label>Centimetros:</label><input class="ingresoDatos" name="cmRMA" id="cmRMA"  type="number"  min="0" required/></li>
                </ul>
            </form>

            <div class="btnContenedor">
                <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" id="btnRegistroMarcaAtleta" class="btnSubmit" />
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please verify if you are having only one element with these `id` in your page?

Comment: For me its working fine see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n6p71zhx/

Comment: I had repeated IDs in the inputs, which I fixed.
But the IDs of the form are unique.
Problem persists.

Comment: @user2020618 Try to compare with this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/ks4wrxtw/

Comment: Tried the format changes, just in case, with no results.

Comment: @user2020618: Are you using script on `$( document ).ready()`, please try by putting script at bottom

Comment: @GauravP I am. My code is in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2bL9jagt/. Relevant function is on line 179.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had arranged form as below, basically form shall not be nested as per XHTML validation. Once you fix this your issue will be sorted in the fiddle which you had posted.

Hope this helps

```
 <form id="formRegistroMarcaAtleta">
..
 <form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaTiempo"></form>
...
 <form id="formRegistroMarcaAtletaDistancia"></form>
</form>
```

Comment: That did it.
Thanks!